# Dropdown menu UIView opened from button in UITableviewCell not clickable outside of cell bounds

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios12, swift5

I am trying to make a button open up a dropdown menu styled UIView inside of a custom UITableViewCell. And it does open the UIView containing the other buttons. Great. However, the only clickable part is the tiny little bit of "1" inside the UITableViewCell. The rest of the dropdown menu is not clickable and you can click through it to the cell below. How can I make the button in the custom UITableViewCell open up the UIView with the dropdown menu and have each button inside the UIView clickable?

Here is what it's looking like now.
[image: screen 1]
[image: screen 2]
[image: screen 3]

```
//The button inside the UITableViewCell:


class PriorityButton: UIButton, DropDownDelegate {
var dropDownView = DropDownView()

var height = NSLayoutConstraint()
var isOpen = false

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    dropDownView = DropDownView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    dropDownView.delegate = self
    dropDownView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "UnChecked"), for: .normal)
    //        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked"), for: .selected)
    self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    self.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Avenir Next", size: 24)
}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    self.superview?.addSubview(dropDownView)
    self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(dropDownView)

    dropDownView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    dropDownView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    dropDownView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    height = dropDownView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if isOpen == false {

        isOpen = true

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])

        if self.dropDownView.priorityTableView.contentSize.height > 300 {
            self.height.constant = 300
        } else {
            self.height.constant = self.dropDownView.priorityTableView.contentSize.height
        }


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.dropDownView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.dropDownView.center.y += self.dropDownView.frame.height / 2
        }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        isOpen = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
        self.height.constant = 0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.dropDownView.center.y -= self.dropDownView.frame.height / 2
            self.dropDownView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

func dismissDropDown() {
    isOpen = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
    self.height.constant = 0
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.dropDownView.center.y -= self.dropDownView.frame.height / 2
        self.dropDownView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func dropDownPressed(string: String) {
    self.setTitle(string, for: .normal)
    self.dismissDropDown()
}
}
```

// The Drop Down Menu view

```
class DropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let priorityLevel = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var priorityTableView = UITableView()
var delegate: DropDownDelegate!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = .white

    priorityTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
    priorityTableView.backgroundColor = .white
    priorityTableView.delegate = self
    priorityTableView.dataSource = self
    priorityTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(priorityTableView)

    priorityTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    priorityTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    priorityTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    priorityTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return priorityLevel.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = priorityLevel[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = .white
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("test")
}
}
```

Expected results:
I want to click on the "1" button in the custom UITableViewCell and it show the dropdown menu UIView and be able to click on the buttons contained within the dropdown menu.

Comment: Its better to add a picker view to popup from the bottom with a title of selected row title. Because that is a most recommended apple terms in Ui documentation.

Comment: I added a popover view and now i'm trying to add a collection view to that so it's horizontal and looks cool. Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the horizontal collection view or not?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the drop down is added to the super view of the cell (aka the tableView) and the delegate of the dropdown is assigned to the cell itself hence it won't respond to the tap gesture recognizer since the table view is not the delegate of it and the tap should occur on the cell, try adding it to the subView of the cell instead of the superView maybe that'll work. Good luck